# Pandas change column to string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe and when I do `df.dtypes` in shows the column is an object

I do `df["column_name"] = df["column_name"].astype(str)`

and again check df.dtypes it still shows the column type as object. Any idea bow to fix this.

When I do `df['column_name'].to_string().dtype`

I get an error
`AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'dtype'`

Comment: Try `df["column_name"] = df["column_name"].astype("string")`

Comment: @bigbounty I tried using this too, it doesn't work

Comment: Refer https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html for different ways to converting to string

Comment: if your try print(df['column_name'].dtypes) - what do you get?

Comment: It says object @ChristianMagelssen

Comment: I tried the df['column_name'].to_string().dtype on many of my dataframes that I know only have string/objects and they all return the same error as you.

Answer (score 1):

In Pandas, there are only these datatypes: boolean, integer, float, datetime and  **object**. Objects are almost always strings but can be any Python object. This is the reason why df.dtypes shows an object.

Comment: I want to convert it to string as I'm unable to do a join on the column. But the conversion doesn't work.

Comment: it's just a regular dataframe and converting the object to string isn't working how it usually works for some reason.

Comment: I have had similar issues. One time I had to convert it to .astype(int) before .astype(str). Other types it has been due to missing values

Comment: I updated the question with some new info not sure if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Series can be converted to the string datatype, give this a try:

```
df['column_name'] = pd.Series(df['column_name'], dtype="string")
```

Or give this a try

```
df['column_name']=df.column_name.convert_dtypes()
```

Comment: @JohnConstantine See my answer